# asp.net AjaxControlToolkit CalendarExtender: setting displayed month programmatically from client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Is there a way to set the calendar extender, or a method I can call so it always displays the month containing the selected date when the target textbox is clicked? I have found the method to set the selected date, but this does not automatically bring the month of the selected date into view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the `onClientShown` event:

```
<cc1:calendarextender ID="Calendarextender1"
    OnClientShown="clientShown" ...
```

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clientShown(sender, args) {
        var extender= $find('Calendarextender1');
        sender.set_visibleDate(extender._selectedDate);
        // the following is just to show you some other interesting methods
        //sender.set_todaysDate(extender._selectedDate);
        //sender.set_selectedDate(extender._selectedDate);
    }
</script>
```

I'm afraid there's no documentation, so try them out.

Comment: thanks, that pointed me in the right direction. The documentation of the ajaxcontroltoolkit is really shockingly incomplete.